# Generate a 10x10 Matrix Using Random Function: How to loop new set of numbers, sum of column and row

Tags: c, matrix, random

Hi I need help since the problem given to me is to make a code that would

Generate a 10x10 matrix using rand function to fill the said matrix with random numbers
Then print all the numbers in matrix form
Then ask the user the following options
OPTIONS:
a: Total sum per row
b: Total sum per column
c: Display all ODD numbers horizontally
d: Display all EVEN numbers horizontally
e: Display all PRIME numbers horizontally
f: Generate new set of random numbers
g: Close the program

All the options is working except option a,b, and f, it does not correctly compute sum of col and row and my codes do not generate new set of random numbers. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int isPrime(int n)
{
    int c=0;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
            c+=1;
    }
    if(c==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int my_array[10][10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            my_array[i][j]=rand()%20;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
            printf("%d\t ",my_array[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    while(1)
    {
        char ch;
        printf("\nSHOW \na.) Total sum per column\nb.) Total sum per 
row\nc.) Display all ODD numbers horizontally\nd.) Display all EVEN numbers 
horizontally\ne.) Display all PRIME numbers horizontally\nf.) Generate a new 
set of random numbers\ng.) Exit the program");
        printf("\n\nOption:");
        scanf(" %c",&ch);
        if(ch=='a')
        {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                printf("%d",i+1);
                int sum=0;
                for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                {
                    sum+=my_array[j][i];
                }
                printf("%d\n",sum);
            }
        }
        else if(ch=='b')
        {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                printf("%d",i+1);
                int sum=0;
                for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                {
                    sum+=my_array[i][j];
                }
                printf("%d\n",sum);
            }

        }
        else if(ch=='c')
        {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                {
                    if(my_array[i][j]%2==1)
                        printf("%d ",my_array[i][j]);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if(ch=='d')
        {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                {
                    if(my_array[i][j]%2==0)
                        printf("%d ",my_array[i][j]);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if(ch=='e')
        {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                {
                    if(isPrime(my_array[i][j])==1)
                        printf("%d ",my_array[i][j]);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if(ch=='f')
        {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                {
                    my_array[i][j]=rand()%20;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(ch=='g')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the documentation for [`rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) tell you about the number it generates, and how to *seed* it? What does all examples using `rand` do first of all (before calling `rand`)?

Comment: As for the other problems, to make it easier to debug don't use random numbers but instead use a fixed set of numbers where the results of all operations are known beforehand. Now, when you debug your program, for example by stepping through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values, when and where does things start to go wrong?

Comment: It is what was asked in the problem to use rand function

Comment: For options a and b, shouldn't you print a space between the row (or column) number and the sum?

Comment: Off-topic: `isPrime`: You know that comparisons are guaranteed by standard to result in either 0 or 1? So please don't do `if(comparison) return 1; else return 0;`, just write `return comparison;`. Then you might compare explicitly for 2 once, then from 3 onwards in steps of 2 as long as `i*i <= n` – that way avoid quite a number of needless comparisons (but not all). Could look as follows: `if(n % 2 == 0) { return false; } for(int i = 3; i*i < n; i += 2) { if(n % i == 0) { return false; } } return true;`

Comment: Also, do you need to print the new set of random numbers for option c?

Comment: If a teacher asks you do use "X" then you need to *research* this "X" and how to use it. The term "use X" almost always implies "initialize so X can be used". Also, if a teacher has told you to use "X" then the teacher should have covered "X" and the possible initialization needed, or at least mentioned where in your text-books or online the needed information can be found.

Comment: You should pack the code for assigning random numbers in a function of its own to avoid duplicate code – then call that initially and on option f.

Comment: Off-topic: As you are just playing around, it's not really a matter – you still might want to keep in mind that `rand() % SomeLimit` produces rather bad distribution. Better is `rand() * SomeLimit / RAND_MAX` – though depending on size of limit and `RAND_MAX` you might have to consider potential overflow...

Comment: For efficiency: `printf` results in system calls, you might want to prefer just a single one instead of two: `printf("%d %d\n", i + 1, sum);` – with additional readability and aesthetic advantage (personal oppinion, though).

Comment: It looks pretty much as if, for option f, your code indeed *does* generate new numbers, but you do not print out them to screen. You should see changed sums of rows and columns then, but new values themselves only get visible to you if you use a debugger.

Comment: Recommendation: I'd prefer a switch block over that long `if/else` chain – and if you like, you can avoid duplicate code for c and d as follows: `if(char == 'c' || char == 'd')` or `case 'c': case 'd': { int v = ch == 'c'; /* results in 0 or 1 just as you need */ for(i) { for(j) { if(myArray[i][j] == v) { /* print */ } } }`

Comment: In C for booleans you shouldn't compare against the `true` values, if at all, compare for not being `false` (`if(value != 0)`), this is safer (admitted, *your* function is guaranteed to return 1 or 0, but still). You can have that shorter, and for boolean semantics I'd definitely prefer: `if(isPrime(n))` (equivalent to `!= 0`).